# python gtk window.show() outside the __init__

Tags: python, gtk

I'm trying to write a Gtk script to notify the user (in root), because I've problems with python-notify in root.
So, I've wrote this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import gtk.gdk
import time

class Time:

    def auto(self, Time, donnees=None):

        print "Show the window"
        self.window.show()
        time.sleep(10)
        print "Hide the window"
        self.window.hide()

    def __init__(self):

        color = "#000"
        positionX = 1560
        positionY = 35

        # Création fenetre principale
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_POPUP)

        # Position de la fenetre principale
        self.window.move(positionX+100, positionY)
        self.window.set_default_size(250, 80)
        self.window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_NONE)
        self.window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER_ON_PARENT)

        # Couleur de la fenetre
        map = self.window.get_colormap()
        colour = map.alloc_color(color) 
        style = self.window.get_style().copy()
        style.bg[gtk.STATE_NORMAL] = colour
        self.window.set_style(style)   

        #self.window.show()

        self.auto(self, Time)

def main():
        gtk.main()
        return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
        Time()
        main()
```

The problem is I can't show or hide the window when I want. When I call self.auto(self, Time) in the **init** the window don't appear.
Does I must use a different thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace your `time.sleep(10)` with:

```
then = time.time()
while then + 10 > time.time():
    while gtk.events_pending():
        gtk.main_iteration()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

to let the main loop run while you are sleeping.

Comment: Another option is to use `gobject.timeout_add(10000, lambda: self.window.hide())`, which will allow the main loop to run without the 0.1s hiccups. Nested main loops tend to attract bugs.

Comment: Please don't use sleep() and gtk.main_iteration(). It will just make for poor app interactivity. Simply using `gobject.timeout_add(10000, self.window.hide)` should work (no need for the lambda).